# Charpit's Method for Nonlinear Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Who is the inventor of Charpit's method?  why was this never discussed in many books and never used in the settlement of partial differential equations if it's very useful for solving the Nonlinear PDE?

Comment: By Charpit's method do you mean the [method of characteristics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics)?

Comment: The inventor of Charpits method was.. Charpit.

Comment: I think it's a little bit different. Charpit's Methos is general solution for Nonlinear PDE. But why i can't find this material on several books

Comment: You can, it's also called the Lagrange-Charpit method and the method of characteristics. The names are often interchanged.